# Cannot retrive service object properties in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, session

I am developing application in angularjs and wish to store some session variables.

My code for app.js is contains controller, service and factory:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function ($scope,
                                               AuthService, Session) {
  $scope.currentUser = null;
  this.Session = Session;
  console.log(Session);
  console.log(Session.id);

  $scope.isAuthenticated = AuthService.isAuthenticated;

  if (!$scope.isAuthenticated()) {
    AuthService.login();
  }

});

app.service('Session', function () {

    var session = {};

    session.create = function(sessionId, userId, userRole) {
        session.id = sessionId;
        session.userLogin = userId;
        session.userRole = userRole;
    };

    session.destroy = function () {
        session.id = null;
        session.userLogin = null;
        session.userRole = null;
    };

    return session;
});

  app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, Session) {
    var authService = {};

    authService.login = function () {
      return $http
        .get('authenticate.php')
        .then(function (res) {
          Session.create(res.data.session_id, res.data.login, res.data.role_id);
        });
    };

    authService.isAuthenticated = function () {
      return !!Session.id;
    }

    return authService;
  });

})();
```

authenticate.php can contain for example following json:

```
{"session_id":"076d89db-141a-11e5-8e8f-18a9059996df","login":"test","role_id":"2","error":null}
```

The problem is, that I can not retrieve session variables (fields of `Session` object), even if they are set. During initialization of controller, I print `Session` variable and it contains all the fields - `id`, `userName`, `userRole`, but when I print `Session.id`, I get undefined value.

How do I access these fields?

Thanks, Zbynek

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never used the `this` syntax for services and have no idea how it works - I use the following kind of syntax, which has worked well both for service functions + storing variables.

```
app.service('Session', function () {

    var session = {};

    session.create = function(sessionId, userId, userRole) {
        session.id = sessionId;
        session.userLogin = userId;
        session.userRole = userRole;
    };

    session.destroy = function () {
        session.id = null;
        session.userLogin = null;
        session.userRole = null;
    };

    return session;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that, but no luck so far. I have edited the post, so now it contains complete app.js file and json, expected by the factory

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
app.service('Session', function () {
  var session = this;
  this.create = function (sessionId, userId, userRole) {
    session.id = sessionId;
    session.userLogin = userId;
    session.userRole = userRole;
  };

  this.destroy = function () {
    session.id = null;
    session.userLogin = null;
    session.userRole = null;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the app still behaves the same. I have edited the post, so now it contains complete app.js file and json, expected by the factory

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the console logging happens before the AuthService starts to create the Session, that additionally uses an async http request - so I'm sure it's members will always be undefined at that time.

Try to move the logging after the `Session.create(res.data.session_id, res.data.login, res.data.role_id);` call.

Comment: actuallly, the first logging (object `Session`) logs the object with all its attributes, only the subsequent logging - `Session.id` logs undefined value. First time, the Session is empty, but on refresh, it should (and does) contain values, I am just enable to access them.

Comment: So you create the Session somewhere else before it's used in the ApplicationController?

Comment: No, I would like to declare Session only once - during first visit of the page, user is authenticated (`AuthService.login()`) and his credentials are stored in `Session`. After refresh, I would like to check, whether session id is set, and if it is, then omit the step, where i try to authenticate the user